# read array in a config file in C#

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

By now, I'm using a configuration file like this in order to set which environtment my application must to work with:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="environment" value="demo"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I'm reading it as follow:

```
AppSettingsSection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( 
    (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(LESTBackend))).Location).AppSettings;
```

From now then, I need to modify the configuration file in order to let whoever who want add some more information like `host`, and `port`. I need to say my application is connecting to two endpoints, so using the old xml style I'd need something like this:

```
    <endpoints>
      <webapi host="hhh" port="1111"/>
      <authz host="hhh2" port="2222"/>
    </endpoints>
```

How could I add this information to my configuration file, and how could I read it?

Up to now, I've been able to create from classes in order to abstract my configuration sections and elements:

Main section (`BackendSection`):

```
public class BackendSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    public const string BACKEND_ATTRIBUTE = "backend";

    [ConfigurationProperty(BackendSection.BACKEND_ATTRIBUTE, IsRequired = true)]
    public ScopeElement Scope
    {
        get
        {
            return (ScopeElement)this[BackendSection.BACKEND_ATTRIBUTE];
        }
        set
        {
            this[BackendSection.BACKEND_ATTRIBUTE] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So, each `BackendSection` contains one `ScopeElement`. Each `ScopeElement` has a `scope` name an array of `EndpointElements`:

```
public class ScopeElement : ConfigurationElement
{

    public const string SCOPE_ATTRIBUTE = "scope";
    public const string ENDPOINTS_ATTRIBUTE = "endpoints";
    public const string ENDPOINT_ATTRIBUTE = "endpoint";

    [ConfigurationProperty(ScopeElement.SCOPE_ATTRIBUTE, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Scope
    {
        get
        {
            return this[ScopeElement.SCOPE_ATTRIBUTE] as string;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(ScopeElement.ENDPOINTS_ATTRIBUTE, IsRequired = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(EndpointsCollectionElements), AddItemName = ScopeElement.ENDPOINT_ATTRIBUTE)]
    public EndpointsCollectionElements Endpoints
    {
        get
        {
            return (EndpointsCollectionElements)this[ScopeElement.ENDPOINTS_ATTRIBUTE];
        }
    }

}
```

So,

```
public class EndpointsCollectionElements : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public EndpointElement this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as EndpointElement;
        }

        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);

            this.BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    public new EndpointElement this[string responseString]
    {
        get { return (EndpointElement)BaseGet(responseString); }
        set
        {
            if (this.BaseGet(responseString) != null)
                this.BaseRemoveAt(this.BaseIndexOf(this.BaseGet(responseString)));

            BaseAdd(value);
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new EndpointElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((EndpointElement)element).App;
    }
}
```

And `EndpointElement`:

```
public class EndpointElement : ConfigurationElement
{

    public const string HOST_ATTRIBUTE = "host";
    public const string PORT_ATTRIBUTE = "port";
    public const string APP_ATTRIBUTE = "app";

    [ConfigurationProperty(EndpointElement.HOST_ATTRIBUTE, IsRequired = false)]
    public string Host
    {
        get
        {
            return this[EndpointElement.HOST_ATTRIBUTE] as string;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(EndpointElement.PORT_ATTRIBUTE, IsRequired = false)]
    public int Port
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this[EndpointElement.PORT_ATTRIBUTE];
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(EndpointElement.APP_ATTRIBUTE, IsRequired = false)]
    public int App
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this[EndpointElement.APP_ATTRIBUTE];
        }
    }
}
```

Could anybody tell me how to write a `.config` file and how to read it using these classes?

This `.config` file would be right?

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="backend" type="Backend.Implementations.Lest.Settings.BackendSection"
  </configSections>
  <backend scope="QA">
      <endpoints>
        <endpoint host="localhost" port="1111" app="webapi"/>
        <endpoint host="localhost" port="2222" app="authz"/>
      </endpoints>
    </backend>
</configuration>
```

Comment: just a side note, you probs only need  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` unless the settings you want arent in the settings file for the current executable (which would be kinda wierd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom configuration section.

There's the MSDN: How To : [How to: Custom Configuration Sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

As an aside, unless you're opening a configuration file for another executeable, you can just use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""]` to reference the currently executing configuration file `AppSettings` section.

Comment: you should include some example code here (not just a link) see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: I've edited my post. As far I've been able to get from your links, I've created four classes: `BackendSection`, `ScopeElement`, `EndpointsCollectionElements` and `EndpointElement`. However, the problem that comes me up is that I don't know how to write a `.config` file and how to read it.